# If I restore from an old Time Machine backup, can I still access newer files from the backup drive?

Tags: backup, time-machine, restore

I want to restore my Mac from Catalina back to Mojave using a Time Machine backup from last year. I have some other, newer files created since then that I would like to keep, so will I be able to still see those on the Time Machine drive if I restore?

I don't mind if it's through the Time Machine interface or just in Finder. The drive is encrypted but I have the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bit the bullet and restored back to Mojave.

For anyone who has the same question - the answer is yes, I can still see my backups on the Time Machine hard drive, however the Catalina Time Machine format is different to the Mojave one, so I can't access files from the newer backups using the Time Machine app.

However the data is there and can be restored using something like `rsync`.

**Edit with another lesson**

Something I didn't know but accidentally saved myself from: Photos on Catalina (Photos 5) stores your photos differently to Photos on Mojave (Photos 4).

Photos 4 uses a logical table structure like:

```
Originals/Year/Month/Day/Photo Name.jpeg
```

Photos 5 uses a uuid structure:

```
Originals/1/14cb2e19-7088-4252-8fd2-ed18b9750ba2
```

For some reason, [Time Machine doesn't backup the Photos database](https://max.town/b-4ZHOV1QJm2wbE-G9Uf4Q/ucMQEO99QmqAqeDJuEaX6w.html). So my method of downgrading and then rsync'ing the newer backup wouldn't work for Photos since rsync would not recognise the different folder structures. Luckily I was paranoid and took a separate, manual backup to a different disk before downgrading.

This manual backup had everything, including the Photos database. This meant I was able to use the python package [osxphotos](https://github.com/RhetTbull/osxphotos) to read the Photos 5 database and pull out any photos newer than my old backup, then import those into my restored Photos 4 library.

```sh
osxphotos --db backup/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary export --export-by-date --from-date 2019-07-01 restored-photos
```

**tl;dr** before downgrading, take a separate, manual backup of your Photos library, or at least the `./Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/database` folder so that you can restore any photos newer than your Mojave backup.